# MySQL design and relations

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship

I'm creating one project for restaurants where user can browse and choose food. I didn't made before such a think and have some troubles with design and relations in database tables. This is the case

```
1. Restaurants
2. Customer click on restaurant-1 
3. Customer get menu list for foods and drinks 
4. Customer browse the food via sub-categories ( Salads, Drinks, Desserts and so on )
5. Customer choose some food and drinks...
```

As I can see here I would need 4 main tables `restaurants`, `meals`, `meal_types` and `menu`. Table `Restaurants` will hold restaurants

```
id
name
menu
image
text
address
```

Table `Meal_types` will hold main meal category - Drinks, Salads, Desserts and so on

```
id
name
```

Table `meals` will hold all foods/drinks

```
id
name
image
text
weigh
price
```

Table `menu` must keep which food/drinks to which restaurant to show when is selected.

```
id
name
```

So here is the tricky/hard part for me. How to make relations between them. One of the relations that I see and must have is between `meals` and `meal_types`. But others? How to connect `restaurants` with them and when user click on some restaurant to see the food that is served only from this restaurant. First thought for me was with this table `menu` but don't know how exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to Name the `ids` according to the items they represent. So I would suggest to Name the column `id` in your table `restaurant` `Restaurant_id`. This might help you Keep the general view in your relations.

Start from your smallest part: Your table `meals`. You have to combine this table with your `Meal_types` table since you have a 1:1 relationship between both (each meal has exactly one type, so just add another colum `meal_type` to `meals`).

Second you have your `restaurants`.

Now you just need an Information about the meals a Restaurant offers. This Translation table is your table `menue` and holds columns like this:

```
Restaurant_id,
Meal_id
```

To get the menue of a certain Restaurant you would query

```
SELECT
    meals.meal_type, meals.name, meals.price
FROM 
    restaurant, menue, meals
WHERE
    Restaurant.restaurant_id = menue.restaurant_id
    AND menue.meal_id = meals.meal_id
    AND Restaurant.name = 'Mc Donald's'
```